# Poor screen share using Agora Virtual Camera Prefab from oculus

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm currently working on an unity project, where I'm trying to screenshare my content from oculus quest 2 to a remote pc with audio chat enabled using Agora Virtual Camera Prefab package. I actually followed this blog for the implementation https://www.agora.io/en/blog/how-to-build-a-vr-video-chat-app-using-unitys-xr-framework/. I successfully implemented this and connected with a remote pc, but all I'm experiencing is a very poor screenshare of oculus(most of the times black screen) in the remote pc. But audio is better only a lag of 1 or 2 sec, plus even I'm able to see the remote pc user's cam video inside my game through oculus. It'll be lot helpful if anyone could help me with this issue, I'm totally stuck with this. I'm also attaching [screenshot of the agora virtual camera prefab's config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQohM.png) and the code used for any suggestions.

```
using System.Collections;
using agora_gaming_rtc;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static agora_gaming_rtc.ExternalVideoFrame;
using agora_utilities;

using System.Collections.Generic;
#if (UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID)
using UnityEngine.Android;
#endif

public class AgoraVirtualCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
#if (UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER && UNITY_ANDROID)
    private ArrayList permissionList = new ArrayList();
#endif

    // PLEASE KEEP THIS App ID IN SAFE PLACE
    // Get your own App ID at https://dashboard.agora.io/
    [Header("Agora Config")]
    [SerializeField]
    private string AppID = "";
    [SerializeField]
    private string TempToken = "";
    [SerializeField]
    private string TokenServerURL = "";
    [SerializeField]
    private string ChannelName = "";
    [Header("Env Config")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera VirtualCam;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject RemoteVideoRoot;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject RemoteScreenVideoRoot;
    /*[SerializeField]
    private int ScreenShareUID;*/
    [SerializeField]
    private Text LogText;

    [Header("UI Btn Config")]
    public GameObject JoinBtn;
    public GameObject LeaveBtn;
    public GameObject MicBtn;
    public GameObject QuitBtn;
    public Color ActiveMicColor = Color.green;
    public Color DisabledMicColor = Color.red;

    [Header("Video Encoder Config")]
    [SerializeField]
    private VideoDimensions dimensions = new VideoDimensions
    {
        width = 1280,
        height = 720
    };
    [SerializeField]
    private int bitrate = 1130;
    [SerializeField]
    private FRAME_RATE frameRate = FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_30;
    [SerializeField]
    private VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_TYPE mirrorMode = VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_TYPE.VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_DISABLED;
    // use bitrate: 2260 for broadcast mode

    // Pixel format
    public static TextureFormat ConvertFormat = TextureFormat.RGBA32;
    public static VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT PixelFormat = VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_RGBA;

    private static int ShareCameraMode = 1;  // 0 = unsafe buffer pointer, 1 = renderer image

    // used for setting frame order
    int timeStampCount = 0; // monotonic timestamp counter

    // perspective camera buffer
    private Texture2D BufferTexture;
    // output log
    private Logger logger;

    // uid
    private uint UID = 0; // 0 tells the agora engine to generate the uid

    // reference to the active agora client
    static AgoraInterface client = null;

    // keep track of remote UID
    Dictionary<string, List<uint>> RemoteUIDs = new Dictionary<string, List<uint>>();

    // keep track of channel state
    bool InChannel = false;

    #region --- Life Cycles ---
    void Awake()
    {
        // keep this alive across scenes
        //DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CheckAppId();// ensure an AppID is defined

        // if there isn't a join button defined, autojoin
        if (JoinBtn == null || !JoinBtn.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            JoinChannel();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PermissionHelper.RequestMicrophontPermission();
        PermissionHelper.RequestCameraPermission();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        LeaveChannel();
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool paused)
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.EnableVideo(paused);
            client.EnableAudio(paused);
        }
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        ShareCameraMode = 0;
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Leave();
            client.UnloadEngine();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region --- Agora Functions ---
    void ReloadAgoraEngine()
    {
        client = GetComponent<AgoraInterface>();
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Leave();
            client.UnloadEngine();
            Destroy(client);
            client = null;
        }
        client = gameObject.AddComponent<AgoraInterface>();
        client.SetLogger(logger);
        // video config 
        VideoEncoderConfiguration videoEncodeConfig = new VideoEncoderConfiguration
        {
            dimensions = this.dimensions,
            frameRate = this.frameRate,
            bitrate = this.bitrate,
            orientationMode = ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_LANDSCAPE,
            mirrorMode = this.mirrorMode
        };
        client.SetVideoEncoderConfig(videoEncodeConfig);
    }

    // agora functions
    public void JoinChannel()
    {
        // clean up and create a new one
        ReloadAgoraEngine();


        string appidMSG = string.Format("Initializing client with appid: ${0}", AppID);
        logger.UpdateLog(appidMSG);
        client.LoadEngine(AppID); // load engine

        // Set up the texture for rendering POV as a texture
        if (VirtualCam.isActiveAndEnabled)
        {
            logger.UpdateLog("Virtual Camera is Active and Enabled, Enable custom video source");
            client.CustomVideo = true;
            int width = Screen.width;
            int height = Screen.height;
        }

        AddCallbackEvents(); // add custom event handling

        if (TokenServerURL != "")
        {
            client.JoinWithTokenServer(ChannelName, UID, TokenServerURL);
        }
        else
        {
            // joing with or without a token
            client.Join(ChannelName, TempToken, UID);
            string joiningChannelMsg = string.Format("Joining channel: {0}, with uid: {1}", ChannelName, UID);
            logger.UpdateLog(joiningChannelMsg);
        }
    }

    public void LeaveChannel()
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Leave();
        }
        DisableSharing();
        InChannel = false;
        // change mic buttn text and color - help user visualize  they left the channel
        if (MicBtn != null)
        {
            MicBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "MIC";
            MicBtn.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
        }
        // remove the remote video planes
        if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            if (RemoteVideoRoot?.transform.childCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (Transform child in RemoteVideoRoot.transform)
                {
                    GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
                }

                StartCoroutine(UiUpdate(0.5f));
            }
        }
    }

    public void ToggleMic()
    {

        if (!InChannel)
            return; // only toggle mic when in a channel 

        Text MicBtnText = MicBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        Image micBtnImg = MicBtn.GetComponent<Image>();

        if (micBtnImg.color == Color.green)
        {
            client.MuteLocalAudioStream(true);
            MicBtnText.text = "Mic OFF";
            micBtnImg.color = DisabledMicColor;
        }
        else if (micBtnImg.color == Color.red)
        {
            client.MuteLocalAudioStream(false);
            MicBtnText.text = "Mic ON";
            micBtnImg.color = ActiveMicColor;
        }
        else
        {
            client.MuteLocalAudioStream(true); // mute by default
            MicBtnText.text = "- MUTED -";
            MicBtnText.color = Color.white;
            micBtnImg.color = DisabledMicColor;
        }
    }


    // Called by quit button
    public void ExitApp()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // Application.Quit() does not work in the editor so
        // UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying need to be set to false to end the game
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
        Application.Quit();
#endif
    }

    #endregion

    #region --- Callback handlers ---
    protected virtual void AddCallbackEvents()
    {
        IRtcEngine mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine();
        mRtcEngine.OnJoinChannelSuccess += OnJoinChannelSuccess;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserJoined += OnUserJoined;
        mRtcEngine.OnUserOffline += OnUserOffline;
    }

    public void OnJoinChannelSuccess(string channelName, uint uid, int elapsed)
    {

        InChannel = true;

        if (VirtualCam != null && VirtualCam.isActiveAndEnabled)
        {
            logger.UpdateLog("Enable Virtual Camera Sharing");
            EnableVirtualCameraSharing();
        }
        else
        {
            logger.UpdateLog("ERROR: Failed to find perspective camera.");
        }


        // update mic button color and text - visually show joined channel
        if (MicBtn != null)
        {
            MicBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "MIC ON";
            MicBtn.GetComponent<Image>().color = ActiveMicColor;
        }

        // enable dual stream mode
        IRtcEngine mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine();
        mRtcEngine.EnableDualStreamMode(true);
    }

    public void OnUserJoined(uint uid, int elapsed)
    {
        // add video streams from all users in the channel 
        // offset the new video plane based on the parent's number of children. 

        //float xOffset = RemoteVideoRoot.transform.childCount * 3.5f;
        //MakeVideoView(uid, RemoteVideoRoot, new Vector3(xOffset, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0));

        // to restrict which user video streams appear 
        // only show users with uid 100-1009 or 49024 (screen share)", 
        // uid 49024 is an arbitrary number that was selected and hardcoded as uid for the screen share stream from the web demo code. This uid can be customized
        string remoteUIDtype;
        if (uid >= 1000 && uid <= 1009)
        {
            // offset the new video plane based on the parent's number of children.    
            float xOffset = RemoteVideoRoot.transform.childCount * -3.69f;
            MakeVideoView(uid, RemoteVideoRoot, new Vector3(xOffset, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(270, 180, 0), new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5625f));
            remoteUIDtype = "admin";
        } else if (uid == 49024 && RemoteScreenVideoRoot != null)
        {
            MakeVideoView(uid, RemoteScreenVideoRoot, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1.777f,-1.0f, -1.0f));
            remoteUIDtype = "screen";
        }
        else
        {
            IRtcEngine mRtcEngine = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine();
            // unsubscribe from video & audio streams
            mRtcEngine.MuteRemoteVideoStream(uid, true);
            mRtcEngine.MuteRemoteAudioStream(uid, true);
            remoteUIDtype = "peer";
        }

        // keep track of the remote uids
        logger.UpdateLog($"Make Remote Video UID type:{remoteUIDtype}");
        if (RemoteUIDs.ContainsKey(remoteUIDtype))
        {
            RemoteUIDs[remoteUIDtype].Add(uid);
        } else { 
            RemoteUIDs.Add(remoteUIDtype, new List<uint> { uid });
        }
    }

    public void OnUserOffline(uint uid, USER_OFFLINE_REASON reason)
    {
        logger.UpdateLog("onUserOffline: update UI");
        // update the position of the remaining children
        StartCoroutine(UiUpdate(0.5f));
    }
    #endregion

    #region --- misc helper functions ---
    public void SetResolution(VideoDimensions newDimensions, int newBitrate)
    {
        dimensions = newDimensions;
        bitrate = newBitrate;

        VideoEncoderConfiguration videoEncodeConfig = new VideoEncoderConfiguration
        {
            dimensions = this.dimensions,
            frameRate = this.frameRate,
            bitrate = this.bitrate,
            orientationMode = ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_LANDSCAPE,
            mirrorMode = this.mirrorMode
        };
        client.SetVideoEncoderConfig(videoEncodeConfig);
    }

    private void CheckAppId()
    {
        logger = new Logger(LogText);
        logger.DebugAssert(AppID.Length > 10, "Please fill in your AppId");     //  Checks that AppID is set.
    }

    private void MakeVideoView(uint uid, GameObject parentNode, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
    {
        logger.UpdateLog(string.Format("Make Remote Video View for UID: {0}.", uid));
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(uid.ToString());
        if (go != null)
        {
            return; // reuse
        }

        // create a GameObject and assign to this new user
        VideoSurface videoSurface = makePlaneSurface(uid.ToString(), parentNode, position, rotation, scale);
        if (videoSurface != null)
        {
            // configure videoSurface
            videoSurface.SetForUser(uid);
            videoSurface.SetEnable(true);
            videoSurface.SetVideoSurfaceType(AgoraVideoSurfaceType.Renderer);
            videoSurface.SetGameFps(30);
        }
    }

    // VIDEO TYPE 1: 3D Object
    public VideoSurface makePlaneSurface(string goName, GameObject parentNode, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Vector3 scale)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);

        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        go.name = goName;
        
        go.transform.localScale = scale; // scale the video (4:3)


        if (parentNode != null)
        {
            go.transform.parent = parentNode.transform;
            go.transform.localPosition = position;
            go.transform.localRotation = rotation;
            Debug.Log("add video view");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("parentNode is null video view");
            go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0f);
            go.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(270, 0, 0);
        }

        // configure videoSurface
        VideoSurface videoSurface = go.AddComponent<VideoSurface>();
        return videoSurface;
    }

    IEnumerator UiUpdate(float time)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        // update the UI
        for (int i = 0; i < RemoteVideoRoot.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            float xOffset = -1 * i * 3.69f; // calculate the new position
            RemoteVideoRoot.transform.GetChild(i).localPosition = new Vector3(xOffset, 0, 0); // update the position 
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region --- Virtual Camera video frame sharing ---
    void EnableVirtualCameraSharing()
    {
        RenderTexture renderTexture = VirtualCam.targetTexture;
        if (renderTexture != null)
        {
            BufferTexture = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, ConvertFormat, false);
            StartCoroutine(CoShareRenderData()); // use co-routine to push frames into the Agora stream
        } else
        {
            logger.UpdateLog("Error: No Render Texture Found. Check Virtual Camera.");
        }
    }

    void DisableSharing()
    {
        BufferTexture = null;
    }

    IEnumerator CoShareRenderData()
    {
        while (ShareCameraMode == 1)
        {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            ShareRenderTexture();
        }
        yield return null;
    }

    private void ShareRenderTexture()
    {
        if (BufferTexture == null) // offlined
        {
            return;
        }
        Camera targetCamera = VirtualCam; // AR Camera
        RenderTexture.active = targetCamera.targetTexture; // the targetTexture holds render texture
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, targetCamera.targetTexture.width, targetCamera.targetTexture.height);
        BufferTexture.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
        BufferTexture.Apply();
        byte[] bytes = BufferTexture.GetRawTextureData();
        // sends the Raw data contained in bytes
        //monoProxy.StartCoroutine(PushFrame(bytes, (int)rect.width, (int)rect.height,
        //() =>
        //{
        //    bytes = null;
        //}));

        StartCoroutine(PushFrame(bytes, (int)rect.width, (int)rect.height,
         () =>
         {
             bytes = null;
         }));

        RenderTexture.active = null;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Push frame to the remote client.  This is the same code that does ScreenSharing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">raw video image data</param>
    /// <param name="width"></param>
    /// <param name="height"></param>
    /// <param name="onFinish">callback upon finish of the function</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerator PushFrame(byte[] bytes, int width, int height, System.Action onFinish)
    {
        if (bytes == null || bytes.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Zero bytes found!!!!");
            yield break;
        }

        IRtcEngine rtc = IRtcEngine.QueryEngine();
        //if the engine is present
        if (rtc != null)
        {
            //Create a new external video frame
            ExternalVideoFrame externalVideoFrame = new ExternalVideoFrame();
            //Set the buffer type of the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.type = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_BUFFER_TYPE.VIDEO_BUFFER_RAW_DATA;
            // Set the video pixel format
            externalVideoFrame.format = PixelFormat; // VIDEO_PIXEL_RGBA
            //apply raw data you are pulling from the rectangle you created earlier to the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.buffer = bytes;

            //Set the width of the video frame (in pixels)
            externalVideoFrame.stride = width;
            //Set the height of the video frame
            externalVideoFrame.height = height;

            //Remove pixels from the sides of the frame
            externalVideoFrame.cropLeft = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropTop = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropRight = 10;
            externalVideoFrame.cropBottom = 10;
            //Rotate the video frame (0, 90, 180, or 270)
            externalVideoFrame.rotation = 180;
            // increment i with the video timestamp
            //externalVideoFrame.timestamp = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            externalVideoFrame.timestamp = timeStampCount++;
            //Push the external video frame with the frame we just created
            int a = 0;
            rtc.PushVideoFrame(externalVideoFrame);
            if (timeStampCount % 100 == 0) Debug.Log(" pushVideoFrame(" + timeStampCount + ") size:" + bytes.Length + " => " + a);
        }

        yield return null;
        onFinish();
    }
    #endregion
}
```